# Is there any AWS api for getting the value of default.s3.multipart_chunksize specified in the ~/.aws/config file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I want to get the value of `default.s3.multipart_chunksize` property configured by the user in `~/.aws/config` file for which I'm trying to find if there is any AWS api in java.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, here?  Also, note that the parameter name is a bit deceptive, since multipart uploads do not actually use [tag:chunked-encoding].   That tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configure this variable in your `/.aws/config` file, you can retrieve the value using [`aws configure`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)

```
aws configure get default.s3.multipart_chunksize
```

From Java, the [`AWSStaticCredentialsProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.html) API does not offer the ability to return additional properties

Comment: As ~/.aws/config file is user-defined meaning each user has a separate config file. I'm curious to know how and where is the chunk size being read through AWS Java code.